Issues with Azure.Identity and DefaultAzureCredential in Unit Tests for CosmosClientFactory
I'm encountering issues with the DefaultAzureCredential in my unit tests when running them in an Azure Pipeline. The error messages indicate that several credential types, such as AzurePowerShellCredential, AzureDeveloperCliCredential, EnvironmentCredential, and ManagedIdentityCredential, are unavailable.
CosmosClientFactoryTests.cs -
    using Azure.Identity;
    using Azure.Core;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
    using Microsoft.DigitalWorkplace.GCS.CommonAPI.DbClient.Factories;
    using Microsoft.DigitalWorkplace.GCS.CommonAPI.DbClient.Models.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;
    using Xunit;

 namespace Microsoft.DigitalWorkplace.GcsApi.CommonApi.DbClient.Tests.Factories
{
   public sealed class CosmosClientFactoryTests
{
    #region Constructor Tests
    [Fact]
    public void Constructor_ThrowsNullExceptionForNullParam()
    {
        ArgumentNullException exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new CosmosClientFactory(logger: null));
        Assert.Equal("Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger')", exception.Message);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Constructor_CreatesInstanceForNonNullLogger()
    {
        CosmosClientFactory cosmosClientFactory = CreateCosmosClientFactory();
        Assert.NotNull(cosmosClientFactory);
    }
    #endregion

    #region GetCosmosClient Tests
    [Fact]
    public async void GetCosmosClient_ReturnsExpectedClient()
    {
        CosmosClientFactory cosmosClientFactory = CreateCosmosClientFactory();

        CosmosDbClientSettings clientSettings = new CosmosDbClientSettings
        {
            CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri("https://localhost:8081/").ToString(),
            ManagedIdentityClientId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", // Static dummy GUID for unit test
            CommonAPIContainerSettings = new ContainerSettings
            {
                ContainerName = "TestContainer",
                DatabaseName = "TestDb",
            },
        };

        TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = clientSettings.ManagedIdentityClientId });
        _ = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }), CancellationToken.None);
        CosmosClient actualClient = cosmosClientFactory.GetCosmosClient(clientSettings);

        Assert.NotNull(actualClient);
        Assert.Equal(clientSettings.CosmosDBEndpoint, actualClient.Endpoint.ToString());

        clientSettings = clientSettings with { CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri("https://testhost:8081/").ToString() };
        _ = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }), CancellationToken.None);
        actualClient = cosmosClientFactory.GetCosmosClient(clientSettings);

        Assert.NotNull(actualClient);
        Assert.Equal(clientSettings.CosmosDBEndpoint, actualClient.Endpoint.ToString());
    }
    #endregion

    #region Helper Methods
    private static CosmosClientFactory CreateCosmosClientFactory()
    {
        using NullLoggerFactory loggerFactory = new NullLoggerFactory();
        ILogger<CosmosClientFactory> mockLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<CosmosClientFactory>();
        return new CosmosClientFactory(logger: mockLogger);
    }
    #endregion
}

}

Can you provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline and the detailed debugging logs of the failed tests? In addition, did you ever manually run the test project using Visual Studio or the vstest command or the dotnet test command on you local develop machine? Do all the tests work fine on local? If the test project never run successfully on your local, it is not possible to guarantee it can work in pipeline.

In local the solution is fine and tests are fine, just want to know the process of testing default azure credntials while migrating to managed identity in the unit test classses

On you local, did you use the same test codes with the same configurations as that in pipeline to run the test project? What do you mean about "the process of testing default azure credntials while migrating to managed identity in the unit test classses"? @Nagarjun

Are you using the cosmo db emulator ?
